# Failed Implicit Static Member Initialization by Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization, c++14, static-members

Take the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int i, typename T = int> struct A
{
    T num = i;
    A<i, T>()
    {
        cout << "Instantiated a A<" << i << ">" << endl;
    }
};

template<int i, int i2> struct B
{
    static A<i> a;
    static A<i * i2> a2;
};
template<int i, int i2> A<i> B<i, i2>::a{};
template<int i, int i2> A<i * i2> B<i, i2>::a2{};

template<typename T> struct C
{
    static void doSomething()
    {
        cout << "Have a A<" << T::a.num << "> and a A<" << T::a2.num << "> in C" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef C<B<2, 2>> c;
    cout << "Typedefined a C\nCalling static member function to initialize C<B<2, 2>>'s B<2, 2>'s A<>s" << endl;
    c::doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Now with gcc, then this compiles (both C++11 and C++14) and [instantiates `a` and `a2` as expected](http://ideone.com/0TOIWQ).

Thanks to WhozCraig, this also compiles with clang.

However with Visual C++ (2015 edition), I get a parse error.

```
main.cpp(37) error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<end Parse>'
```

Followed by some notes

```
main.cpp(19): note: while compiling class template static data member 'A<2,int> B<2,2>::a'
main.cpp(26): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'B<2,2>' being compiled
main.cpp(25): note: while compiling class template member function 'void C<B<2,2>>::doSomething(void)'
main.cpp(33): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void C<B<2,2>>::doSomething(void)' being compiled

main.cpp(33): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'C<B<2,2>>' being compiled
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Fwiw, this compiles with clang 3.8, std=c++14 no problem as well. I am, however, confused how `main.cpp` line 37 can be reporting an error, when the entire code you posted for reproduction has only 34 lines thru the closing `}` in `main()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig The Visual implemenation has 2 more lines (an include and `_getch()`). Strange to me too that it reports an error after the end of the file...

Comment: `A<i, T>()` What is this syntax doing?

Comment: @NicolBolas A constructor. It's to check when the static As are initialized from B

Comment: @OutlawLemur: Right, but what's with `<i, T>`? The constructor `A` is a member of a template class `A`; it doesn't need to have the template parameters there to be able to access them. And I'm surprised that compiles.

Comment: @NicolBolas Huh, I've just always used them for clarity's sake

Comment: @OutlawLemur Remove the `<i, T>` from constructor's name and your problem should be fixed. I concur with Nicol Bolas that the way you named the constructor should not compile.

Comment: @Leon Same errors on Visual Studio

Comment: @NicolBolas We can just use `A()` because of injected-class-name, and everybody always does, so while `A<i,T>()` looks super weird, it's not wrong (except in the sense that I don't think I've ever seen anybody do that, which makes it look super awkward).

Comment: @NicolBolas See [class.ctor]/1.2. Any *class-name* that names the current instantiation (and that isn't a *typedef-name*) will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reduce the test case, identify the problem (which appears to be a bug in the Visual C++ compiler) and find a workaround:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int i> struct A
{
    int num = i;
    A() {}
};

template<int i> struct B
{
    static A<i> a;
};

// MSVC doesn't like this syntax
//                         |||
//                         vvv
template<int i> A<i> B<i>::a{};

// To fix the error, rewrite the above line in one of the below ways:
//
// template<int i> A<i> B<i>::a;
// template<int i> A<i> B<i>::a = {};

int main() {
    typedef B<2> B2;
    cout << B2::a.num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh microsoft... Thanks

Comment: Did you report the bug to Microsoft? If so, can you please post a link to the bug report here?

Comment: @ildjarn No, I didn't.